# How to create 2 different manifest.json file for react project with 2 entry points using webpack ManifestPlugin?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, manifest

I have a react project contains two modules with 2 entry points. I have configured the web pack in a way to create two bundles (js) in the output folder like below.

```
dist 
   - Project Output 1
      - index.js
      - index.html
      _ manifest.json

   - Project Output 1
      - index.js
      - index.html
      - manifest.json
```

I had created separate index.html for each bundles using chunks. Similarly, I need to create seperate manifest file for each bundle. Need help on doing that. So far I have tried filter and map in the manifest plugin but both generated manifest file contains information of both bundles.

Both manifest.json of project bundle 1 and 2 contain the same information like below.

```
{
   //What is not intended
   "path1/index.js": "path1/index.1234567890.js",
   "path2/index.js": "path2/index.1234567890.js",
}
```

But what i wanted is each manifest file contain information about that bundle alone like below.

manifest.json - Project bundle 1

```
{
   "path1/index.js": "path1/index.1234567890.js",
}
```

manifest.json - Project bundle 2

```
{
   "path2/index.js": "path2/index.1234567890.js",
}
```

My web pack config looks like below.

```
const config = {  
  entry: {
    ProjectOutput1: PATH1/index.jsx,
    ProjectOutput2: PATH2/index.jsx,   
  },   
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/index.js'   
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin(
      fileName: 'path1/manifest.json'
    ),
    new ManifestPlugin(
      fileName: 'path2/manifest.json'
    )]
 };
```